# Combining results from multiple cypher match statements

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to combine any nodes returned by one of three match conditions:

```
(p)-[:HAS_CAL]->(prodCal:ProdCal)-[:DELIVERS_TO]->(:Country {name: "USA"})
(p)-[:HAS_CAL]->(prodCal:ProdCal)-[:DELIVERS_TO]->(z:ZipCode {zipCode: delivZip})
(p)-[:HAS_CAL]->(prodCal:ProdCal)-[:DELIVERS_TO]->(zr:ZipRange) where zr.fromZip >= delivZip or zr.thruZip <= delivZip
```

With any results that come back from any of those match conditions I'd like to then perform another match. I'm guessing that means using either a foreach or unwind, in a fashion such as this:

```
unwind prodCals as prodCal
match (prodCal)-[dd:DELIVERS]->(delivDay:Day) where dd.cutoff > (timestamp() / 1000)
return delivDay
```

I've tried several things but cannot get this to work. The end result should be a set of `delivDay`s that are returned by each of the `match (prodCal)-[dd:DELIVERS]->(delivDay:Day) ...` statements.

**Update:**

I seem to have a solution that works:

```
...
with p, delivZip
optional match (p)-[:HAS_CAL]->(prodCal1:ProdCal)-[:DELIVERS_TO]->(z:ZipCode {zipCode: delivZip})
with p, delivZip, prodCal1
optional match (p)-[:HAS_CAL]->(prodCal2:ProdCal)-[:DELIVERS_TO]->(zr:ZipRange) where zr.fromZip >= delivZip or zr.thruZip <= delivZip
with p, collect(prodCal1) + collect(prodCal2) as prodCals
optional match(p)-[:HAS_CAL]->(prodCal3:ProdCal)-[:DELIVERS_TO]->(:Country {name: "USA"})
with collect(prodCal3) + prodCals as prodCals2
unwind prodCals2 as cal
match (cal)-[dd:DELIVERS]->(delivDay:Day) where dd.cutoff > (timestamp() / 1000)
return delivDay
```

I'd love to know if there is a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH p, delivZip
MATCH (p) - [:HAS_CAL] -> (prodCal:ProdCal)
WHERE (prodCal) - [:DELIVERS_TO] -> (:Country {name: "USA"})
OR (prodCal) -[:DELIVERS_TO] -> (:ZipCode {zipCode: delivZip})
OR ANY( path IN (prodCal) - [:DELIVERS_TO] -> (:ZipRange) WHERE delivZip >= LAST(NODES(path))['fromZip'] AND delivZip <= LAST(NODES(path))['thruZip'] )
WITH prodCal
MATCH (prodCal)-[dd:DELIVERS]->(delivDay:Day) WHERE dd.cutoff > (TIMESTAMP() / 1000)
RETURN delivDay
```

Elegance is a subjective property, of course, but this avoids having to worry about `COLLECT/UNWIND` shenanigans, you'll avoid errors from accidental `NULL` results from `OPTIONAL MATCH`, and it'll be incidentally more performant. If you have the option to refactor, I would replace those `:ZipRange` nodes with relationships to individual `:ZipCode` nodes; even if you have to make 100000 relationships, that's well within capacity, and will simplify all your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to understand `OR ANY( p IN (prodCal) - [:DELIVERS_TO] -> (:ZipRange) WHERE delivZip >= LAST(NODES(p))['fromZip'] AND delivZip <= LAST(NODES(p))['thruZip'] )` better... why the use of `OR ANY` when looking at matches to the ZipRange nodes? Also, why check only the last node in the list for the fromZip and thruZip (`delivZip >= LAST(NODES(p))['fromZip']`)?

Comment: Ah. So what the statement inside the parentheses does is go over every path `path` that matches the pattern, then for each path, checks to see if the last node in the path `path`(`LAST(NODES(path))`, the `:ZipRange` node) expresses a range in which the the `delivZip` falls. If there is at least one path of that pattern that passes this filter, the `ANY` then evaluates as `True` and your `prodCal` will be passed on in a result row. (fixed variable name to reduce confusion).

Comment: Oh very cool! Regarding your other point about creating a `:DELIVERS_TO` relationship for every zip code represented by a `ZipRange` node, would that not effectively make a `ProdCal` node a super node? I thought that having, for example, 80,000 to 100,000 relationships going out of a single node to be bad practice? To expand on my concern this is a query pattern that will happen very often and must be as fast as possible.

Comment: I think this is mostly an article of faith left over from older versions, I haven't observed a problem  with relationship numbers well above that since 3.0. YMMV, of course.

Comment: I see, I will have to experiment with both patterns and see how they compare. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @novon did you notice any super node-related performance issues in Cypher? I'm also facing a similar situation and was wondering if you had any observations on query performance you could share between the `ZipRange` and `ZipCode` approaches

Comment: sorry @prrao we decided to abandon the neo4j POC and go with a more traditional solution so I can't comment on performance in production